# Distributing inflation in a hierarchical model

Tags: reference-request, price-index

I am trying to distribute inflation in a hierarchical model.  In both of the following two scenarios, the [Laspeyres' Index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Price_index#Paasche_and_Laspeyres_price_indices) over the entire data set is 1.8; However, in the first scenario, the inflation is caused by a rise in prices in Florida.  i.e. the inflation is 1.8, and is caused by a change in relative prices between states.  In the second scenario, the inflation is caused by a rise in the price of Juice everywhere.  i.e. the inflation is 1.8 and is caused by a change in relative prices between products.

I would like a metric that captures this intuition in a general scenario that gives a ratio (or something like it) of inflation-causality of price redistribution between states and price redistribution between products.  I have not been able to find anything in the literature, and I am having difficulty diving anything.  Any direction is appreciated.

(note that the quantity at time 1 doesn't enter into the calculation, it's just displayed for completeness)

**SCENARIO 1**

```
+---------+-------+-------------+--+-------------+
|         |       | time 0      |  | time 1      |
+---------+-------+-------------+--+-------------+
|         |       | price | qty |  | price | qty |
+---------+-------+-------+-----+--+-------+-----+
| Florida | Nuts  | 1     | 10  |  | 2.6   | 5   |
+         +-------+-------+-----+--+-------+-----+
|         | Juice | 2     | 20  |  | 5.2   | 40  |
+---------+-------+-------+-----+--+-------+-----+
|         |       |       |     |  |       |     |
+---------+-------+-------+-----+--+-------+-----+
| Alabama | Nuts  | 1     | 10  |  | 1     | 5   |
+         +-------+-------+-----+--+-------+-----+
|         | Juice | 2     | 20  |  | 2     | 40  |
+---------+-------+-------+-----+--+-------+-----+
```

**SCENARIO 2**

```
+---------+-------+-------------+--+-------------+
|         |       | time 0      |  | time 1      |
+---------+-------+-------------+--+-------------+
|         |       | price | qty |  | price | qty |
+---------+-------+-------+-----+--+-------+-----+
| Florida | Nuts  | 1     | 10  |  | 1     | 5   |
+         +-------+-------+-----+--+-------+-----+
|         | Juice | 2     | 20  |  | 4     | 40  |
+---------+-------+-------+-----+--+-------+-----+
|         |       |       |     |  |       |     |
+---------+-------+-------+-----+--+-------+-----+
| Alabama | Nuts  | 1     | 10  |  | 1     | 5   |
+         +-------+-------+-----+--+-------+-----+
|         | Juice | 2     | 20  |  | 4     | 40  |
+---------+-------+-------+-----+--+-------+-----+
```